Модель БД для системы с вещами (товарами)
Есть задача по описанию вещей. Чтоб можно было описывать предметы из различных категорий, с разными атрибутами и т.д.
Сначала, хотел у сущности "Вещь" описать базовые поля (Шифр, Владелец, Название, Описание, Место...) и поле Атрибуты типа jsonb. Но данный подход преподаватель раскритиковал.
Поэтому сейчас рассматривают модель EAV. Нарисовал в итоге вот такую (вложение) модель. Но мне сказали "думай еще". Куда можно "копать" дальше?
Upd:
Как понял предложения от SwaD. Вариант 1.

Вариант 2.


Чего он хочет то?
Я бы сказал, например, что атрибуты не только текстовые бывают...

@SergeiKirjanov Классический EAV предполагает одну таблицу значений атрибутов. Соответственно поле значения должно иметь максимально совместимый тип - и это именно текстовый тип данных.

Возможно, ваше задание как по другому звучит или может там есть еще условия? В целом, для "магазина" товаров, подход вполне себе правильный. Единственное, вы его усложнили тем, что название атрибута вынесли в отдельный справочник, да еще и через 2 таблицы. У таблицы itemAttributes сделайте поле Attibute текстовым.

Нарисовал в итоге вот такую (вложение) модель. А тег - он типа не атрибут, да?

@SwaD Теги, планирую как, какие то доп сноски, пометки. "товар пользуется популярностью", "только выложили".  Название атрибута в отдельной таблице, чтоб соотнести категории и атрибуты.
То есть, у соответствующей категории товаров, свои атрибуты

Это может и имеет смысл... однако посмотрите с точки зрения выборки данных: Что бы по товару отобразить список атрибутов, вам надо заджойнить сами таблицы с товарами и атрибутами + 3 таблицы, что бы добраться до названия атрибута - это кажется перебор

@SwaD это да, тоже верно. В плане производительности будет плохо. Тогда можно отказаться от связи категорий и атрибутов. Но в ИтемАттрибутес будто все равно лучше оставить АйДи на атрибут. Ведь атрибуты у товаров повторятся будут

Ну будут повторяться и что? Какая разница, у вас будут повторяться ключи (1,2,3) или значения (длина, ширина, высота). И кто сказал, что ключи не могут быть текстовые? А если уж вам так хочется, создайте рядом таблицу - атрибут, описание, значение, может еще какие поля и при вставке данных в таблицу атрибутов товара, проверяйте наличие в справочнике. Такая таблица сразу закроет потребность, если позже надо будет рядом с товаром и атрибутом показыввать, что этот атрибут значит

@SwaD обновил пост, я правильно понял ваше предложение?

Вот первый вариант да. А второй не то. Осталяете таблицу itemAttributes с полями [item, attribute, value], и создаете таблицу attributes_references где поля [attribute, description, ... ] - далее уже смотрите, как ее использовать, как строгий справочник или только справочник значений, требующий уточнений. Ну я бы использовал как не строгий справочник. Вобщем попробуйте сдать преподавателю просто первый вариант, а второй показать как "развитие"

Первая пока лучшая. Таблица возможных значений со 2 варианта норм. Но мне не нравится, что вы не поймете какой атрибут как сравнивать, как преобразовывать. Если это перечислимый тип, то хорошо бы знать, что храним id. А если это скажем вес, то сразу захотят дать пользователю искать значение в диапазоне, что как раз не применимо к перечислимым или к тексту. В общем у атрибута не хватает его типа. А теги в принципе те же атрибуты, но они множественные. И вот тут вопрос как хранить множественные значения (которые возможно не только теги)
